# How to keep my header static?

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie and working on a project to learn and improve my web designing skills. I want to know how can I make my header static? It should move down as I scroll down the page. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking for a fixed header that stays in place when scrolling down the page.

The simple solution would be to add a CSS rule such as below to your CSS file and make sure your header html has the id defined as "yourheader"

```
#yourheader { position:fixed; }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this i assume? **[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Q3v2/)**

`position:fixed;`
`top: 0;    = Fixed to top`
`bottom: 0; = Fixed to Bottom`

And so on for left and right...

The html:

```
<div class="header">
    This is my header!!!
</div>
<div class="content">Content goes here!!!!</div>
```

The css :

```
body {
    margin:0;
}

.header
{
    background:#454545;
    position:fixed; 
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    height: 25px;
}

.content
{
    margin: 35px;
}
```